# Rails CSRF Countermeasures on Users edit and update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I'm setting up security on my Rails App according to the [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures).

My understanding is that the 'edit' method in the Users Controller (which I'm using to render my User settings view) should only be submitting a GET request, and that the 'update' method is submitting the POST request. But when I want to verify the types of requests for different methods like this:

```
#UsersController
verify :method => :post, :only => [:update], :redirect_to => {:action => :show}
```

the app doesn't save any of changes made to user settings. And if I change the verification to

```
verify :method => :post, :only => [:update, :edit], :redirect_to => {:action => :show}
```

I can't even render the settings view.

StackOverflow is usually great at educating me on areas I don't know much about, anyone know what could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but a little off.  Here are the seven RESTful routes, and what method they use:

1. index: GET
2. show: GET
3. new: GET
4. create: POST
5. edit: GET
6. update: PUT
7. destroy: DELETE

As you can see, updating requires a PUT. It's creating that uses POST.  This should fix it:

```
verify :method => :put, :only => [:update], :redirect_to => {:action => :show}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! The sentence here is what threw me: "If your web application is RESTful, you might be used to additional HTTP verbs, such as PUT or DELETE. Most of today‘s web browsers, however do not support them – only GET and POST. Rails uses a hidden _method field to handle this barrier." But I guess Rails handles it

Comment: Yeah, it sure does.  It's a necessary evil until browsers catch up :)